# Facing: The method readLine() is undefined for the type String

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

[image]I have java program named P_Builder.java.

```
import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class P_Builder {



        public String PB_Reader( String file_location, String pb_cmd)throws IOException
        {

            File file=new File(file_location);

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/C",pb_cmd);

            pb.directory(file);

            Process p = pb.start();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));

            String readline= reader.toString();
            return readline;
            /*String readline=null;
            do{
            return readline;
            }while((readline = reader.readLine()) != null);*/
        }



    }
```

Now I am using this P_Builder.java in  A.JSP multiples times since I need to run process builder multiple times.

I want the line wise output to of the P_Builder to be sent to A.JSP so that I can read the line wise output using readLine() method and print output using A.JSP where I have omit few lines in output.

A.JSP

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.DecimalFormat"%>
<%@ page import="license_Dashboard.P_Builder" %>
String pcm= "lmutil.exe lmstat -a -c 426@STIOSP569";
P_Builder p1=new P_Builder();
String readline1=p1.PB_Reader("D:\\SINGULA\\Log", pcm);  
String readline;
int j=0;
while ((readline = readline1.readLine()) != null) {
    if(j==2 || j==3 || j==6)
    {
    //out.println(readline);
    //out.println("<br>");
    }
    else if(j>9)
    {
    out.println(readline);
    out.println("<br>");
    }
    else
    {
    //out.println("<br>");
    }
    j++;
    }
```

After I am facing error:- "The method readLine() is undefined for the type String"   in A.JSPin while loop.

UPDATE:- 5:23PM

```
import java.io.*;
        import javax.servlet.*;
        import javax.servlet.http.*;
        import java.lang.*;
        import java.text.*;
        import java.util.*;

        public class P_Builder {



            public String PB_Reader( String file_location, String pb_cmd)throws IOException
            {

                File file=new File(file_location);

                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/C",pb_cmd);

                pb.directory(file);

                Process p = pb.start();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        p.getInputStream()));


                return reader;
                //String readline= reader.toString();
                //return readline;

                /*String readline=null;
                do{
                return readline;
                }while((readline = reader.readLine()) != null);*/
            }


        }
```

Even this Gives error since it needs return as String type. How can I make return type as BufferedReader Since I want to return multiple values as they are read by bufferedReader.

After that can anyone tell How can I catch the values in JSP and print them on webpage.

Update:- 7:00PM

```
 public class P_Builder {



            public String PB_Reader( String file_location, String pb_cmd)throws IOException
            {

                File file=new File(file_location);

                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/C",pb_cmd);

                pb.directory(file);

                Process p = pb.start();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        p.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();
                String readline;

        while((readline = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {


            //this.fin_readline[j]=readline+"\n";
            result.append(readline);
            result.append("\n");


        }
            }
            return result.toString();


        }
```

Now A.JSP Has been modififed:-

```
<%  


 out.println("\n");
    try{
    P_Builder p1=new Test_P_Builder();
    String pcm= "lmutil.exe lmstat -a -c 426@STIOSP569";

    String res=p1.B_Reader("D:\\SINGULA\\Log", pcm);

    String[] lines = res.toString().split("\\n");
    int j=0;
    for(String readline:lines)
    {
        if(j>3)
    {
    out.println(readline);
    }
    j++;
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e);
    }
```

%>

Now the Output is not coming the aligned. The screen print is attached.[image]

Would appreciate you resolution to get the output aligned?

output after giving out.println(readline + "
"); in JSP

Comment: readLine is indeed a method that does not exist in the String class. Your code doesn't make much sense to me. 
I would expect something like:
String line = reader.read(); while ( line != null ){ /* process */ line = reader.read();}

Comment: Your while close is corect but the readline1 variable must be an instance of BufferedReader. so change your PB_Reader function return type to be a BufferedReader instead of String. For information the toString() function is inherited from the object class and will return a string representation of your object and not the stream your are reading

Comment: readline = readline1.readLine()) != null)  this condition will be  either false or true it will not be null. Is that the purpose that code is indended for?

Comment: @MohanRaj `(readline = readline1.readLine())` is `String` -valued, and the comparison of that to `null` is boolean-valued.

Comment: What I want here is that process builder should read all the lines in log file and then return all the lines read to the A.JSP where is I can use to print in the webpage and trim some lines in JSP logic. Since I need to use the P.Builder.java multiple times thats why I am writing code in a Java class

Comment: @jMounir How can I make readline1 variable must be an instance of BufferedReader. I mean here is buffered reader reads line one by one hence will return only one line since it exits after.

Comment: I've not seen the updated version, i was talking about the first one. now you have read the file using the correct way.

Comment: Now for the last question "Now the Output is not coming the aligned. The screen print is attached." you need to add an HTML new line tag "<br>" like this  out.println(readline + "<br>");

Comment: @jMounir The output is still not aligned even after out.println(readline + "<br>"); I have attached the screen print as well.

Comment: That is a brand new question that had nothing whatsoever to do with your prior compile error. Asking it here under a different title isn't a rational strategy. Start a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Your `PB_Reader` method needs to return a `BufferedReader` not a `String`.

`String readline= reader.toString();` this is where you for some reason decide to get the string representation of your reader. Don't do that.

Comment: How to return BufferedReader to A.JSP. ? So that I can use reader.readLine() in A.JSP to get the output.

Comment: With `return reader;`. Not `return readline;`. You're not very experienced with Java, are you?

Comment: Its true I am not very experienced. But if do  return reader; in P_Builder class and comment the while loop. I will face the following error:- Type mismatch: cannot convert from BufferedReader to String

Comment: How Should I modify the name of the PB_Reader method so that it returns  reader (which is fetching the value from BufferedReader)? If i give  public String PB_Reader( String file_location, String pb_cmd) then it will only return sting type.

Comment: Change the return type of the method of course. Then go [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/) for the basics.

Comment: Well Method can take only String, int, long, void  return type their no Buffered reader type. I need to return multiple values as they are read by buffered reader.

Comment: @ManinderSingh The first sentence of that is simply untrue. The second sentence requiress you to call `BufferedReader.readLine()` in a loop. Methods can't return multiple values, so you cannot possibly have such a requirement.